# Variation of 3SAT is in NP-Complete

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines, np-complete, satisfiability

Consider the problem of "K-3SAT", a variation of 3SAT: Given a 3CNF formula O and an integer k, the machine determines whether the formula O has a satisfying assignment in which at most k variables assigned as "true".

I need to prove that it's in NP-Complete by showing a reduction from another known language in NP-Complete (vertex cover, clique, sat, 3sat) to this problem. which one would you suggest?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is offtopic: should be on Computer Science site:
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SAT Problem is origined from set theory. Besides I didn't even know about cs stackexchange, then thanks :)

Comment: Reducing SAT to K-3SAT is trivial: just run the $K-3SAT$ machine with $k$ equal to the number of variables. Thus, K-3SAT is NP-hard. Can you see how to prove it's NP (and thus NP-complete)?

Comment: After some thinking I understood your answer :) thank you very much!